# How do I link to another app from within my App? Information such as deep link documentation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, deep-linking

#### Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am working on a project for work and my current environment is as follows, we have contracted a react native application that has some web-views within the app that my team develops the content for.  Within these web-views we want to have an "Apps" web page where the user will be able to launch company apps.  I have found a couple good deep links (Below) but do not know how to find information regarding the others... Documentation appears to be really spotty for Deep Links and I have even found articles talking about how "Deep Linking" is the wrong terminology.

Is there a native way to determine what links will launch applications or a different terminology I can search for that will get me results?

Working:

- Outlook : ms-outlook://
- Yammer : https://www.yammer.com/yourcompany.com/#/home

Semi Working:

- Microsoft Teams : https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/ gets me into the app but errors out because it cannot find the unspecified channel; I just need to open the app, not go to a specific channel.

Not Working / Cannot find:

- Glint
- SAP Concur

The above examples are very inconsistent and this is very frustrating.  Is there a better/more standard way We should be working to accomplish this?  Please keep in mind that we are working within a web view.

One route I have considered, though I do not know if it will gain any traction, is presenting my team with the option to write native code that will launch the desired application, and register deep links for our application such as "ourApp://link/outlook" or some wild multistep option such as this.  Would this be possible? What would be best practice?  I am not as well versed in native development.

Comment: For anyone who may find this question via a google search; Here are my sources for the working Deep Links:
Outlook: Found it via googling, no official documentation showed me this.
Yammer Docs: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-and-android
Teams Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links

Comment: The info you are searching is in the AndroidManifest.xml stored of each app you want to open. Therefore just download the APK, extract the manifest and look what URL schemes are registered by the app.

Comment: @Robert I have not done anything like this before, can Android Studio unpack an APK?  Also the same question goes for IOS and Xcode.

Comment: In Android Studio select Build -> Analyze APK to see the AndroidMaifest.xml of an APK file. For iOS I assume the data is saved in some binary plist file, but I don't know details.