# Find link name of installed apps on android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

How am I able to find the name of the installed app on the phone so that I can refer to it in react native using linking ? As an example Microsoft teams

Answer (score 0):

You can find app is installed or not [react-native-check-app-install](https://github.com/redpandatronicsuk/react-native-check-app-install)

It shows all the apps which are installed

```
RNAndroidInstalledApps.getApps()
      .then(apps => {
        // apps contains "packageName" and "appName"
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
```

Comment: I’m trying to find the URL name so that I can link to it , I’m trying to find the app name. For example “facebook://“ works and opens the app but I can’t get the Microsoft teams and yammer name

Comment: Check this is what you are asking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132522/how-do-i-link-to-another-app-from-within-my-app-information-such-as-deep-link-d

Comment: I want the name of the app installed on the phone :(

Comment: This could help https://github.com/progaymanalaiwah/react-native-android-installed-apps#readme

Comment: Any ideas, still not found the answer

Comment: If this helps: I need to find the name of Microsoft teams and yammer in order to open it on my apps

Comment: You can traverse the response apps and could find if it has Microsoft teams and yammer installed by equating "packageName" and "appName"

Comment: As I showed you, Just install the library and execute the above code which gives you the installed apps "packageName" and "appName" so you can check is the Microsoft team is installed or not like checking package name === "com.microsoft.teams" if true that means app is installed in phone

Comment: I’m using react-native-app-link, It’s already checking that for me, but the issue is that I cannot find the correct name of app; com.microsoft.teams does not work; for example skype:// and Facebook:// works

Comment: Yes, still not working :/ not sure on what to do now; I really need the names for Microsoft teams and Microsoft yammer